# How to get state value and pass in methods parameters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

how can i use vuex state and use to methods property of components?
I have a state "currentThreadId" but i want to use that state in methods?

what i struggle is i can get the "currentThreadId" in my vuex state using computer property. but i don't know how to pass it to methods. i want to use that id for axios request.

```
 messagesServices.attachEstimate({message_id}).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
 });
```

all i want is the way how to get the id and use to methods property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) there are multiple ways to access state in your components. I'd suggest using the `mapState` helper with the spread operator. For example:

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'currentThreadId',
    ]),
  },
  methods: {
    someMethod() {
      console.log(this.currentThreadId)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy :)  i thought currentThreadId  need to placein data properties. i forgot to console